# Ограничение выполнение команд, Telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, бот

Как сделать команду которой могли бы пользоваться только **определённые пользователи**, а если бы команду использовал *пользователь "не из списка"*, то бот отправлял сообщение, например "Команда доступна только администраторам"?

Comment: Проверяйте id юзера, если id не админский то выдавайте нужную ошибку

Answer (score 4):

```
# Ограничение в команде
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    adm = [123, 456, ...]  # список из id пользователей
    if message.chat.id not in adm:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не дозволено')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Чего изволите сударь?')


# Ограничение выполнение команд start, stop, etc
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id not in users_commands, 
                     commands=['start', 'stop', 'etc'])
def some(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не дозволено')


# Ограничение доступа к боту по ID
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id not in users)
def some(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не дозволено общаться с незнакомцами')
```