# Как ограничить доступ к выполнению команд и Reply клавиатуре?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite, telebot

Всех приветствую!
Подскажите, как ограничить доступ к выполнению команд и пользовательского ввода с Reply-клавиатуры для user_id, которые отсутствуют в базе данных?

С командами пока не придумал.

Но с обработчиками Reply клавиатуры пробовал так:

```
def check_id(message):
    id = message.from_user.id
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM registration WHERE user_id=?', (id, )).fetchone()

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) 
def statistics_step(message): 
    if message.text.lower() == 'анкета 1' and check_id is None:
        one_anketa_step(message)
    if message.text.lower() == 'анкета 2' and check_id is None:
        two_anketa_step(message)
```

Мой способ не сработал, бот совсем перестал реагировать на клавиатуру.

P.S. TelegramBotAPI+SQLite+Python

Comment: Почему функцию check_id вызываете без аргумента? И почему в SELECT выводите все поля а не одно?

Comment: С аргументом косяк, согласен. Пытался и с аргументом, все равно не работало.
А select проверяет все user_id из базы с user_id пользователя.

Comment: Плохая практика писать в селекте звездочку, там достаточно одно поле выводить. Также функция ничего возвращает.

Comment: @dtroyan
Если есть возможность, покажите примером. Не уверен, что в другом случае таблица сравнит все user_id. Но скорее всего, я просто что-то не понимаю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так, что-то вроде этого. Кстати в условиях вы тоже вроде ошиблись, если я правильно понял вашу логику:

```
def check_id(message):
    id = message.from_user.id
    record = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM registration WHERE user_id=?', (id, )).fetchone()
    if record:
        return True
    else:
        return False

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def statistics_step(message):
    if (message.text.lower() == 'анкета 1') and check_id(message):
        one_anketa_step(message)
    if (message.text.lower() == 'анкета 2') and check_id(message):
        two_anketa_step(message)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает)
А на счет выполнения команд /start /menu не подскажите?
Видел подобный вопрос через lamda в примере делали, но там со списком.
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1230730/%D0%9E%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4-telegram-bot]

Comment: Можно сделать также как вы здесь реализовали,  Там проверяется на вхождение в список, а вы сделайте на проверку True

Comment: А именно централизовано на все команды? А не в каждой команде по отдельной проверке.

Comment: Примерно так - func=lambda message: check_id(message) == True

Comment: @дроян, спасибо большое, позже попробую)

Comment: @дроян, получилось, только условие не True, а False.
Спасибо еще раз)

Comment: Круто, не за что)